# The generated voice volume is too low when using the SpeechSynthesisUtterance API in the Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

When using the SpeechSynthesisUtterance API in the Chrome browser on Windows 10, I find that the generated voice volume is not very high.

I have already set the volume parameter to 1, and both the system and Chrome volume are also set to the maximum. However, compared to other playback software, the volume of the API-generated voice is much lower. Is there any way to address this issue?

Comment: Use a different browser and os combo is all you can try.